# I want to use my ADSL Modem+ router as access point using LAN to LAN connection?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I want to use my ADSL Modem+ router as access point.

I already have a wireless router which is working fine.

I want is to extend my network range by using my spare ADSL Modem + router as a second access point using LAN to LAN connection.

Comment: Okay, but what is your question? Is it something that's not yet covered by the dozen similar posts (see the "Related" section ↘)?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a duplicate but:

```
1. Disable DHCP on spare Modem/Router
2. Assign a static IP within the currently used range, preferably at the end for simplicity
3. Configure wireless to mimic primary, but use a different channel
4. Connect to primary via LAN port to LAN port of primary
```